# "@p4 : String truncation: max=4, len=6, value='Female'." error when inserting to database

Tags: c#, sql

i am having a students database with strongly typed dataset. i have 10 columns. the problem is with gender column. whenever i am manually typing in to datagrid and saving its saving fine. but when im importing data from excel file and saving it to database i get this error

@p4 : String truncation: max=4, len=6, value='Female'

I have set the MaxLength to six in dataset.xsd and to nchar(6) in database schema. Below is my code..

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.NewRow();
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows.Add(row);
    this.sbdgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Class"] = dt.Rows[i]["Class"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Section"] = dt.Rows[i]["Section"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Name"] = dt.Rows[i]["Name"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Gender"] = dt.Rows[i]["Gender"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Caste"] = dt.Rows[i]["Caste"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Present"] = dt.Rows[i]["Present"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Meals"] = dt.Rows[i]["Meals"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["DateAdded"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateAdded"];
    this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["DateDeleted"] = dt.Rows[i]["DateDeleted"];
}
```

where dt is datatable filled by excel. and here is the save logic

```
private void studentsDatabaseBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        this.Validate();
        this.bsStudentsDatabase.EndEdit();//binding source
        this.taStudentsDb.Update(this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase);
        MessageBox.Show("Save Successfull.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);   

}
```

can some one tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: It's exactly what the message said. `Female` is six characters, but the database only accepts four characters in the column you're trying to insert that into. Are you maybe inserting it into the wrong column?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Also, try filling in the new `row`, and only _then_ doing the `Add`.

Comment: Hi John. i am not inserting it to wrong column as male entries are inserting without any problem. and only StudentId field which is the primary key is having length of 4.

Comment: Try inserting `Fema` instead and see if that works.

Comment: @John Yes its working if i use only `Fema`

Comment: filling in the new `row` and then doing `Add` is resulting in the following compile error `'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found`

Comment: I mean do the same `this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows.Add(row);`, but do it after you fill out the row.

Comment: If it works for `Fema` but not `Female`, then the column is actually 4 characters, even if you think you changed it to 6.

Comment: as i said if i directly enter it to datagridview its not throwing tantrums. how do u explain that.

Comment: I have no idea, but who do you believe - the DataGridView or the database? Which one is likely to have a better idea of the actual column width? Or, BTW, are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: i am not using any triggers. of course it boils down to database. that is what i cant figure out why the database is not accepting 6 characters when feeding data programmatically. i would be glad to provide any more info or screenshots if required

Comment: What is the actual type of the actual column in the actual database? varchar(4)?

Comment: type:`nchar` length:`6` column: `Gender` i am using sqlce.i am using strongly typed dataset which is bound to datagrid. and i have set `MaxLength` property to 6 in `.xsd` file

Answer (score 1):

```
@p4 : String truncation: max=4, len=6, value='Female'
```

Maximal value for female is four characters and you are trying to insert six characters, you have to reduce length of value you are inserting.

Comment: The OP sasys that he has set the database column to 6 nchar and updated the dataset.

Comment: @Steve: obviously not.

Comment: @JohnSaunders obviously, so that's the problem that need an answer, reducing the input could only confirm that something has gone bad on the change

Comment: @steve seems you understand my issue. have u had any similar issues bro

Answer (score 0):

well i found a workaround. for some reason `DataSetTableAdapter.Update` is not working but when using `DataSetTableAdapter.Insert` everything goes fine. here is the updated save method,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < this.dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            this.taStudentsDb.Insert((byte)dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Class"],
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Section"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Gender"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Caste"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Present"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["Meals"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["DateAdded"].ToString(),
                                     dataSet.StudentsDatabase.Rows[i]["DateDeleted"].ToString() );
        }
       MessageBox.Show("Save Successfull.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

I would request mods not to close this thread if possible since i have not got the proper solution